# Customize mask color of range slider

Tags: plotly

Is this possible to customize mask color of range slider? By mask I mean that gray parts. I would like to change the color to better match page and chart styles.

I checked source of Plotly.js but didn't find any clues.

[image: Picture of range slider]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found an answer myself. It is possible using css:

```
.rangeslider-mask-min, .rangeslider-mask-max {
  fill: rgb(0, 181, 173) !important;
  fill-opacity: 0.3 !important;
}
```